# Redis - Promoting a slave to master manually

Tags: redis

Suppose I have [Slave IP Address] which is the slave of [Master IP Address].

Now my master server has been shut down, and I need to set this slave to be master MANUALLY (WITHOUT using sentinel automatic failover, WITH redis command).

Is it possible doing this without restarting the redis service ? (and losing all the cached data)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use `SLAVEOF NO ONE` to promote a slave to master

http://redis.io/commands/slaveof

Answer (score 2):

it depends, if you are in a cluster you will be better using the fail over. You will need to use the force option in the command

http://redis.io/commands/cluster-failover

Answer (score 2):

> As of Redis version 5.0.0 the `SLAVEOF` command is regarded as deprecated.

If a Redis server is already acting as replica, the command `REPLICAOF NO ONE` will turn off the replication, turning the Redis server into a MASTER.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible doing this without restarting the redis service? (and
>   losing all the cached data)

yes that's possible, you can use
`SLAVEOF NO ONE` (without sentinel)

But it is recommended to use sentinel to avoid data loss.
`sentinel failover master-name`(with sentinel)
This will force the sentinel to switch master.
The new master will have all the data that was synchronized before the old-master shutdown.
Redis will automatically choose the best slave with max. data, that will reduce the amount of data we lose when switching master.

Comment: `sentinel failover master-name`
has to be run in the Sentinel command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Below 2 options in step 3 have helped me to recover the cluster once a master node is down, compute was replaced or other not recoverable state.

- 1 .- First you need to connect to the slave node, use redis-cli, here a link how to do that: [How to connect to remote Redis server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678865/how-to-connect-to-remote-redis-server)
- 2 .- Once connected to the slave node run the command `cluster nodes` to validate master node is in `fail state`, also run `cluster info` to see the overall state of your cluster(this is always a good idea)
- 3 .- Inside the slave node to be promoted run command: `cluster failover`,
  in rare cases when there is some serious issues with redis this
  command could fail, and you will need to use `cluster failover force`
  or `cluster failover takeover`, here more info abut the implications
  of those options: https://redis.io/commands/cluster-failover
- 4 .- Run `cluster forged $old_master_id` in all your cluster nodes
- 5 .- Add a new node with `cluster meet $new_node_IP $new_node_PORT`
- 6 .- Subscribe your new node to your brand new master, login in to the new bode and run `cluster replicate $master_node_id`

Steps 1-3 are required for the slave-master promotion and 4-5 are required to left all cluster in a healthy master-slave equilibrium.