# How to connect to remote Redis server?

Tags: redis

I have URL and PORT of remote Redis server. I am able to write into Redis from Scala. However I want to connect to remote Redis via terminal using `redis-server` or something similar in order to make several call of `hget`, `get`, etc. (I can do it with my locally installed Redis without any problem).

Answer (score 448, accepted):

```
redis-cli -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p YYYY
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the IP address and `yyyy` is the port

EXAMPLE from my dev environment

```
redis-cli -h 10.144.62.3 -p 30000
```

[REDIS CLI COMMANDS](http://redis.io/topics/rediscli)

> Host, port, password and database By default redis-cli connects to the
> server at 127.0.0.1 port 6379. As you can guess, you can easily change
> this using command line options. To specify a different host name or
> an IP address, use -h. In order to set a different port, use -p.
>
> redis-cli -h redis15.localnet.org -p 6390 ping

Comment: It says `Could not connect to Redis at -c:6379: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: @ duckertito- ABle to solve this issue ? I'm also facing the same

Comment: You can use `redis-cli -u redis://user:pass@host:port` as well if you don't feel like entering host and port separately..

Comment: The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host 
So `docker run -it --rm bitnami/redis:latest redis-cli -h host.docker.internal -p 6379` should work

Answer (score 98):

There are two ways to connect remote redis server using `redis-cli`:

### 1. Using host & port individually as options in command

```
redis-cli -h host -p port
```

If your instance is password protected

```
redis-cli -h host -p port -a password
```

e.g. if `my-web.cache.amazonaws.com` is the host url and `6379` is the port

Then this will be the command:

```
redis-cli -h my-web.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

if `92.101.91.8` is the host IP address and `6379` is the port:

```
redis-cli -h 92.101.91.8 -p 6379
```

command if the instance is protected with password `pass123`:

```
redis-cli -h my-web.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 -a pass123
```

### 2. Using single `uri` option in command

```
redis-cli -u redis://password@host:port
```

command in a single `uri` form with username & password

```
redis-cli -u redis://username:password@host:port
```

e.g. for the same above host - port configuration command would be

```
redis-cli -u redis://pass123@my-web.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
```

command if username is also provided `user123`

```
redis-cli -u redis://user123:pass123@my-web.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
```

This detailed answer was for those who wants to check all options.
For more information check documentation: [Redis command line usage](http://redis.io/topics/rediscli)

Comment: How to connect to redis that used ssl.
when I tried this ```redis-cli -u rediss://default:passwd@example-redis.aivencloud.com:25945```, it throws ```Invalid URI scheme``` error.

Comment: @Arvin `redis-cli` does not support TLS connections, so you’ll need to use a different tool that supports the `rediss` protocol in order to connect with the URI. I’ll suggest using `redli`(https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/redli) and this command to connect: ```redli --tls -u rediss://default:passwd@example-redis.aivencloud.com:25945```. But if you’re bound to use `redis-cli` then you’ll be needed to do extra config for the same. Check: https://redis.io/topics/encryption

Comment: For using single uri option in Java add database index at end:
Example: if /0, then `redis://user:password@host:port/0`

Answer (score 70):

In Case of password also we need to pass one more parameter

```
redis-cli -h host -p port -a password
```

Comment: Using a password on the command line can be insecure. A more secure version of this is to connect without the password. ```redis-cli -h host -p port``` And then authenticate. ```host:6379> AUTH abcdefg```

Answer (score 15):

One thing that confused me a little bit with this command is that if `redis-cli` fails to connect using the passed connection string it will still put you in the `redis-cli` shell, i.e:

```
redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

You'll then need to `exit` to get yourself out of the shell. I wasn't paying much attention here and kept passing in new `redis-cli` commands wondering why the command wasn't using my passed connection string.

Answer (score 4):

if you got `Error: Server closed the connection`
try with `--tls` switch:

```
redis-cli --tls -h my-redis.redis.cache.windows.net -p 6379 -a myRedisPassword
```

- `h`  hostname
- `p`  port
- `a`  password

Answer (score 1):

If none of these responses are working then try:

```
redis-cli -u rediss://user:pass@host:port
```