# How to read data from redis slave in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, master-slave

we usually follow a pattern where we read from the slaves/clusters node and write to the master node in any database.

I am using Nodejs and trying to figure out to read from the slave node in Redis.
looking at Redis npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis I didn't found any configuration, where we can specify the slave configurations for the read operation.

If you have figured out this already please post sample code here in answer or refer how did you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, master-slave connection is unavailable.   You could try IORedis [How to create a Redis connection with Master and Slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431036/how-to-create-a-redis-connection-with-master-and-slave)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.